# Can I install Windows 8 App Store apps to an SD card?

Tags: windows-8, sd-card, windows-rt, microsoft-surface

On Android it's possible to move apps to a connected SD card. Can I do this with Windows 8 to prevent the built-in memory from filling up?

Comment: This likely would be up to the developer to support.  It certainly should be possible to storage any additional data generate by the application to place said data in a specific storage location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Ricardo Lopez, Test Manager for Surface RT, [you cannot install apps to the SD Card](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/11kyja/iam_panos_panay_gm_of_microsoft_surface_amaa_ask/c6ndgfl) on the Microsoft Surface.

Comment: I think it may be possible to make a folder on the SD card into an NTFS mounted drive in Disk Manager or use a symbolic link, but I don't have a Windows RT device to test yet.

Comment: @paradroid Yeah, I actually edited that idea out of my answer. I know Windows RT has the Command Prompt, but I have no idea what programs are available.

Answer (score 2):

Apps are installed under the `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps` directory. I don't think moving apps in another location is supported or even possible.

Sources:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464929.aspx
- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160312021525/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/zxue/archive/2012/03/08/win8-howto-21-install-and-uninstall-metro-style-apps.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend this since the nature of the SD will be noticeably slower than that of the internal storage space. If you encrypt the data on the Surface then these read/write speeds to the SD card will be even slower. You will soon find that the speed of the Surface is much slower than you would like. I would recommend using the SD card for media storage instead of application storage.